# Remove a word from OpenOffice.org standard dictionary

Tags: macos, openoffice, spell-check

Our company has just named some new software using a regular English word.  My fingers are determined to misspell this word.  Unfortunately, the misspelled word is also a place name that is in the OpenOffice.org standard dictionary, so the misspell is not even being highlighted.  Until my fingers bend to my will :), I'd at least like some visual clue that I have mistyped the word, *again*.

I would have expected something along the lines of http://voices.yahoo.com/how-modify-standard-dictionary-openoffice-6263924.html, but when I select the standard dictionary and click the Edit... button, I get a blank list.  In the enclosed list it indicates that I should be able to type in the word I want then click the Delete button, but when I try that my Delete button remains inactive.

As an end run, I thought I might be able to more directly edit the dictionary. PeterRoots gives a hint about how to do this in http://en.libreofficeforum.org/node/2140, but I'm on a Mac and Spotlight can't find a file named "en_US.dic".

So, how do I remove the place name from the standard OpenOffice.org dictionary on a Mac, so that I get misspell highlighting for that word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't check on an osx, but I have an ubuntu box which should be close enough.

I was able to do Tools --> Options --> Language Settings --> Writing Aids and edit the user-defined dictionaries pretty easily.

You can access all of the dictionaries by also running the spell checker, clicking options and then edit any dictionary including the standard one.

`EDIT:`
I see what you mean on osx. I was able to find the en_US.dic by opening terminal and runnin `find / -name en_US.dic` which searches your full computer for anything named en_US.dic. For me it ended up in /usr/share/hunspell, but that may be my installation (which is older but has been updated to the current version).

Comment: Through the Writing Aids, on my Mac, I can edit any dictionary *except* the standard one.   

I'm glad you gave me the `find / -name en_US.dic` command.  I had two separate dictionaries in my system, but I'm not sure which one had control (both were in /Users/name/Library/Application Support/OpenOffice.org/3/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages/).  I removed the offensive word from both, then restarted OOo and everything worked like I want. :)